# How to create a warped checkered grid in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating templates for sports uniforms in Adobe Illustrator.

The client has asked to create a design that looks like this:

[image: Warped checkered uniform]

How would I go about creating a warped checkered pattern like this?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator: Transform type to give it wave-like form/flow](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84830/adobe-photoshop-illustrator-transform-type-to-give-it-wave-like-form-flow)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cartoon for a start:

[image]

Do not forget the rotation. It affects very differently depending when it's done.

Here's another cartoon for totally other approach:

[image]